# Mongoose with TS and Next.js - problem with models

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I'm using mongoose with Next.js 13 and when defining my models, I'm defining a model for a product dl'ed from the database. But when I run the project, it tells me the models object is undefined and throws an error. I'm using TypeScript, btw.

Here are the imports:

```
import { Schema, model, models } from "mongoose";
```

The export from my models file looks like this:

```
export const Product = models.Product || model("Product", productSchema);
```

And the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Product')

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: make sure you are importing this only at server. you are probably importing it in a client component